# Circle covering theorem proof explainantion

Tags: geometry, proof-writing, proof-explanation, convex-geometry, discrete-geometry

So this question is actually the Circle covering proof by goodman and goodman. But I am not able to find the research paper and few websites that I found are not accessible. If anyone can explain how it is proved I will be thankful;

Suppose segments {$B_{r_1}{(a_1)}$, . . . , $B_{r_n}{(a_n)}$} form a non-separable family of segments. Prove that the segment $B_{r_1+···+r_n}$
(a), where $a =\frac{r_1a_1+···+r_na_n}{r_1+···+r_n}$, covers these segments

What I thought:I considered the various balls of different radius i.e $B_{r_1}{(a_1)}$, . . . , $B_{r_n}{(a_n)}$ centered at $a_1,...a_n$ respectively and projected them on to a line which I believe will make it easy for solving. Now if the intersection of all segment is non-empty then their projection also will be non-empty. Over here I can apply Helly's theorem and can say that all the segments share a common point. But how will I prove that the common point is equal to the point given in the question?

Comment: It seems you are talking about [this paper](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/00029890.1945.11999187) (behind a paywall) doi:10.2307/2304537

Comment: @CalvinKhor Yup but I am not able to access it. That's why I am not able to see the entire proof. I tried doing it myself but I can't do it. I tried the lemma 1 used in the paper to prove the theorem that's also I am able to do.

Comment: The paper can be found on a certain website whose name ends with hub and begins with sci, you didn't hear it from me.